# Can I have lambda expression that simply gets object property in Dart2?

Tags: dart

So If I have colelction of some objects like

```
List<QueryParameter> params=[.....]

class QueryParameter {
  String name = null;
}
```

Is there a shorter version of lambda that simple gets property like this

`params.map(QueryParameter.name)` instead of `params.map((param)=>param.name));` ??

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any syntactical sugar for creating a lambda that just returns an object property.

However, you could use Dart 2.3's collection-`for` to avoid using `map` and lambdas entirely:

`[for (param in params) params.name]`

which is shorter *if* you need the result to be a `List` instead of an `Iterable`; that is, it's slightly shorter than:

`params.map((param) => param.name).toList()`

or

`[...params.map((param) => param.name)]`